# Jersey ResourceConfig doesn't auto discover but Application does?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

When I have a very basic `Application`, Jersey auto discovers all the REST resources in the project and I don't have to manually register them:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class Application extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

}
```

But when I switch to using the Jersey specific `ResourceConfig`, auto discovery doesn't seem to work.  I have to either `#registerClasses()` or add the package as shown below:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ResourceConfig  extends org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig {
    public ResourceConfig() {
        super();        
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        super.packages(true, "org.example");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get `ResourceConfig` to auto discover the REST resources like `Application` without having to register the classes individually or having to add the application's package?

Answer (score 6):

Here's the deal: What causes classpath scanning, is an `Application` class that does *not* register anything. So in your `ResourceConfig` (which extends `Application`), if you didn't register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`, you'd get the classpath scan. My guess is that you switched to the `ResourceConfig` so that you *could* register the `RolesAllowedDyanamicFeature` (maybe from some example you saw). This could also be done in the `Application` class by overriding the `getClasses()`. But like I said, once you register *anything* you lose the classpath scan, and you need to register everything manually.

One work around is to implement a `Feature` to register all your classes that won't otherwise be picked up by the classpath scan.

```
@Provider
public class ClassPathScanWorkAroundFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeauture.class);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will work for both the `Application` or the `ResourceConfig` class. What happens during the classpath scan, is that Jersey will look for both `@Path` *and* `@Provider` annotated classes to register. So this is find of a workaround to register things manually and still maintain the classpath scan.

One thing I would point out, is the following article by one of Jersey's developers.

- [When to Use JAX-RS Class-path Scanning Mechanism](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/when-to-use-jax-rs-class-path-scanning-mechanism)

Basically they suggest never to use it. Personally I would just stick to the *package* scan. I don't think it really makes life that much more difficult. It's actually *less* code, than the alternative of using the `Feature`.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply to so old article.  Since the article link is lost, is it sill bad to auto discover in Jersey3 / Tomcat 10?